# How to integrate Aurelia in existing classic ASP application

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I work on an old Classic ASP web application, and would like to use Aurelia framework with it. It's easy to get going with Aurelia using the aurelia-cli, but I struggle to find out how to integrate Aurelia in an existing application (which has its own folder structure etc. that deviates from the Aurelia CLI default structure).

I know Aurelia probably is intended for SPAs, but I would love to have "one Aurelia app" per server rendered (.asp) page. Is this possible and how should I set up Aurelia to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for this would be to use the `enhance` feature of Aurelia to enhance an already existing page.

That being said, I'm not sure Aurelia is the right tool for the job you're wanting to use it for. (And I say that as a member of the Aurelia team)

Comment: ok, thanks for your quick response! I've barely looked at the enhance feature, but it seems somewhat unclear to me how I should set up Aurelia when using it. Can I still use aurelia-cli, or would I configure my app differently?